# Magento 2 search by keywords does not works in grid

Tags: magento2, grid, search

In ui_component XML config file, there is a node `<filterSearch name="fulltext">` to control the search box positioned in **listingToolbar**. But seem this full-text search function doesn't work. Does it require a MyISAM table in order to use this function?

I'm looking for an explanation of how to use it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to define the fulltext column while creating Table like this:-

```
  ->addIndex(
        $setup->getIdxName(
            $installer->getTable('table_name'),
            ['column1','column2'],
            AdapterInterface::INDEX_TYPE_FULLTEXT
        ),
        ['column1','column2'],
        ['type' => AdapterInterface::INDEX_TYPE_FULLTEXT]
    )
```